# Issue with ID's in browser when same content is loaded a second time in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website where all my content is loaded into a div name content. my menubar is also loaded in to a div name menu.

The problem arises when i click the same link for a second time. So for instance i would click on members.php for a second time, the content is loaded into the div but some of my functions dont work as expected as they rely on and id which has been set. An ID can only be used once so when i load the page for the second time the ID doenst work. I would have to remove it before loading the content another time (which isnt an option) - as there are many ids.

i would be using jquery to load the content into the div. for instance $('#content').load('members.php');

but upon doing this the second time my id's would not work (content of the first page load stays intact) is there a way to reload that div.

Also is this normal behavior?

Comment: I see 2 options for you: 1- Empty `#content` before loading new content in it. 2- Disable the menu button once the content is loaded.

Comment: well i tryed doing an empty using $(".menudiv").empty() (menudiv is the classname) this doesnt seem to work and i have to reload certain content.. (for instance if i receive a new message the menu needs to be refreshed to reflect that)

Comment: Try with `$(".menudiv").html("");`. `.empty()` only remove text nodes. [reference](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to define if this content loaded before or not, check it every time you call the loading function if it is not loaded before then load it, else no need to reload it again.

```
//initialize members_loaded variable when your page start.
var members_loaded = false;
//then when you want to load data check for it, change it to true in your complete function (when ajax done)
if(!members_loaded){
    $( "#content" ).load( "members.php", function() {
        members_loaded = true;
    });
}
```